# Batch do loop multi to process label controls which having appropriate name

Tags: c#, vb.net, label

I have created 8 labels in the window form, named

> label1,label2,label3,label4,label5,label6,label7,label8

and how can I using loop to process some labels?

This is VB.NET CODE, I want to Convert VB.NET to C#

```
For i=1 to 5
    Me.Controls("label" & i).Visible = False
Next i
```

Update

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
   Control[] lbl = this.Controls.Find("label" + i, true);
   (lbl[0] as Label).Visible = false;

}
```

Comment: You should name your controls, then store them in an array.

Comment: Thanks, I hvae named this controls, I will to try 'store them in an array' .

Answer (score 0):

for i =1 to 5
Next i

is equal with
for(int i =1;i<=5;i++)
{}

and then, you try to get the label by its name

```
for(int i =1;i<=5;i++)
{
Label lbl= this.Controls.Find("label"+i, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
lbl.Visible= false;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include an explanation of your code? It helps the reader more than you might think.

Comment: I'm sorry, for a moment I think it's a webform, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have find the same effect, thanks to reply

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Control[] lbl = this.Controls.Find("label" + i, true);
            (lbl[0] as Label).Visible = false;

        }
    }
```